# Use Windows PC tablet as Wacom Tablet for Mac

Tags: sculpting, grease-pencil

As the title suggests, I would like to know how to turn my Windows PC into a Wacom tablet for my Mac. I've read about solutions that use VNC or a custom built Linux OS, but they do not fit what I need. Preferably, I would like to use some Windows app that can read pen and touch input from my PC and send that data over to my Mac. Somewhat like a Wacom tablet. I intend to use this for the Grease Pencil or sculpting in Blender.

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about using Blender.

Comment: Which Stack Exchange forum would you suggest I post it in?

Comment: Maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/ ? You would have to see what type of questions they accept.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) can do the job. It is possible to run a connection over the local network (which increases speed). In the end, I simply TeamViewered into my Mac from my PC and worked like that.